# Listing LoadBalancers on OpenStack

Tags: python-2.7, load-balancing, openstack

I am trying to create a python script to list LoadBalancers and I keep receiving a message that the resource is not found.  Anyone have a quick script that can list LoadBalancers using Python?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to list the pools and vips:

```
from neutronclient.v2_0 import client as neutron_client

neutron = neutron_client.Client(**credentials)
lb_pools = neutron.list_pools()
lb_vips = neutron.list_vips()
```